# good convention for function return

Tags: python

I have a object instance which needs to be compared against a list of instances of the same class,to find out one with equal attributes.
The attributes to be used for comparing is also provided,and are loaded dynmically every invocation.
At the end ,I need to return the successful instance(if any),the attributes used for comparing,or a list of failed instances along with the differing fields(if none matched).

```
def func(tomatch,listofprospects):
    attrs = <load dynamically>
    for l in listofprospects:
        failues=list()
        mismatch=match(tomatch,l,attrs)#returns any mismatched fields for this element
        if not mismatch:
            return (l,attrs)
        else:
            filures.extend(dict(l.name(),mismatch))
    return(failures,attrs)
```

I am not comfortable with the fact that returning values of the function mean different for different circumstances.
What would be the recommended convention around this?
Also ,can there be a way to accommodate this into a comprehension/map form - inspite of the ugliness of the returning values.

Comment: Proper code indentation is a good convention.

Answer (score 2):

As you are comparing two objects of the same class, the first tip would be to implement your own [`__eq__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) function.

Second, let the consequences of the comparison be left to the caller. Your function should simply say if the objects are equal or not, and the best way of doing that is returning `True` or `False`.